# Strange behavior of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

I noticed a very odd behavior when working with AVPlayer from AVFoundation framework. I'm trying to stream (play) some mp3 radio file from internet.

So I created a new project in Xcode and added the following code to the default ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: "https://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/Newport.mp3")!);
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset);
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player.play();
    }
}
```

There's nothing particularly interesting going on there. I just create an `AVPlayerItem` instance with the radio station URL and give it to AVPlayer and then ask the player object to play the song and it works just as expected.

**However if I remove the `player` object instantiation from the class block and put it in the `viewDidLoad` method the code simply doesn't work (doesn't play anything) yet it doesn't crash or spit out any kinds of errors or warning.**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
        let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: "https://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/Newport.mp3")!);
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset);
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player.play();
    }
}
```

**I can't understand this behavior. Why is that happening? Is it limited to AVPlayer or I should watch out for cases like this?**

Comment: I guess you may want to check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Can you please explain a little bit more. How are these things related?

Comment: In your second example, `player` is going to be deallocated just after `viewDidLoad` is executed, because nobody is pointing to such instance. 
So retain count becomes 1 when you assign the player, then goes to 0 after `viewDidLoad`. In the first example the retain count is 1 and remains 1 because, such player is a stored property of `ViewController`, which retains the `player` (until is not being deallocated, in such case also `player` is supposed to be deallocated)

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini So how do I make sure that `player` is safe for the entire life cycle of my app? Because a music player is supposed to keep working even in background.

Comment: I don't know how your app it's structured, be sure such `player` is kept in a "safe" place (might be the `ViewController`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrea Mugnaini explained in the comments to my post, my second example is going to cause an **immediate deallocation** by the **ARC** (Automatic Reference Counting) as we don't keep a **strong reference** to the AVPlayer object.

This is a common pitfall of developers new to Apple's ecosystem.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening in my case. Always make sure the variable is global or at least non-deallocateable when you're setting up the AVAudioPlayer/AVPlayer in order to keep the player alive. Otherwise, Swift will just think we no longer need the variable reference.